# How to use Applescript to open a printer app and select items within?

Tags: applescript, automator, printing, canon

I have absolutely no knowledge or experience in using Applescript or Automator. I'm hoping by using either to create an app (or script) that will print a test page off my printer automatically. I know how to open the printer app (Canon iX6800 series.app), but I'm stuck from there with the dialog box not knowing how to continue to do the following steps:

1. Run "Canon iX6800 series" - I got this part…
2. Select "Settings" or Command S
3. Select "Utility"
4. Select "Print Test Page"
5. Click "OK"
6. Quit the app.

Any suggestions or help will be greatly appreciated. I can send the actual app to whoever might need it. Thanks in advance.
George

Comment: Did you try [using Automator’s “watch me do” script making genius wizardry?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255092/automator-watch-me-do-function-does-not-work-in-app)

Comment: I did try "watch me do" and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've roughly translated your steps into a working AppleScript:

```
tell application "Canon iX6800 series" to activate -- Run "Canon iX6800 series"
delay 0.25
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Canon iX6800 series"
    click menu item "Canon iX6800 series" of menu "Window" of menu bar 1
    click menu item "Settings" of menu "Printer" of menu bar 1 -- Select "Settings"
    click radio button "Utility" of tab group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 -- Select "Utility"
    click button "Print Test Page" of tab group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 -- Select "Print Test Page"
    key code 53 -- escape key (selects Cancel)
end tell
tell application "Canon iX6800 series" to quit -- Quit the app
```

Note that the part at the beginning (with the delay and window selection) is necessary to ensure that an active window is open in the printer app; otherwise, the Settings panel won't be able to open if a window isn't already open.

---

Although the following isn't what the OP is asking for, in case anybody else is looking to do this with a printer that doesn't supply a "Print Test Page" option in the Settings panel, here's an alternate solution:

1. Open the "Canon iX6800 series" app
2. Click the "Print Test Page" menu item in the "Printer" menu
3. Quit the app

To accomplish this, replace lines 5–7 of the above with `click menu item "Print Test Page" of menu "Printer" of menu bar 1`.

Comment: Thank so much for your help in creating the script that produce mostly what I'm looking for. The only problem is it's giving me a different Test Page than the one I need. There are two possible Test Page that can be printed and the one I need will need to add a couple more steps in order to get there. I will try to explain what I've done so far, and what else is needed to get to the other Test Page in the next message…

Comment: So far I've kept the first and the last line, and made changes to part of the second line from:
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Canon iX6800 series" to click menu item "Print Test Page" of menu "Printer" of menu bar 1
to
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Canon iX6800 series" to click menu item "Settings" of menu "Printer" of menu bar 1

Now it opens up "General", "Supply Levels", "Utility", and I need to click on Utility
Then it opens up "Open Printer Utility" and "Print Test Page". That's the "Print Test Page" I need to select.

Comment: @GeorgeMok Thanks for clarifying—you might see if the new version of the script works (I've edited my answer).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the new version and it worked but it's giving me the other Test Page (the wrong one). So I tried the longer version without replacement of line 5-7 and it gave me the correct Test Page I was looking for. But the app did not quit and gave me an error "error "Canon iX6800 series got an error: User canceled." number -128".
I also realized that the "Cancel" button has to be clicked before the app would quit. I'm not sure how to avoid the error at the same time apply the Cancel before quitting.

Comment: @GeorgeMok Is it possible you could share some screenshots of the flow that's supposed to occur in the printer app? I can't seem to emulate these screens on my own Mac.

Comment: I'd love to do that but I'm not sure how. I searched everywhere and couldn't find any instructions on posting screenshots.

Comment: @GeorgeMok When you're editing your post, you can click the image icon in the toolbar at the top and upload a picture from your computer. To take a screenshot on a Mac, press Shift-Command-3—the file should save to your desktop by default.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I finally realized why I couldn't insert any images; my toolbar is missing. I also tried Ctrl + G and that didn't work neither. I searched for solution to reclaim my toolbar without any success. Apparently it has been a problem for a lot of people in the past.

Comment: So far I have tried to fix (patch) it not knowing what I was doing, and it seems to work okay as shown below:
tell application "Canon iX6800 series" to activate
delay 0.25
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Canon iX6800 series"
click menu item "Canon iX6800 series" of menu "Window" of menu bar 1
click menu item "Settings" of menu "Printer" of menu bar 1
click radio button "Utility" of tab group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
click button "Print Test Page" of tab group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
key code 53
end tell
tell application "Canon iX6800 series" to quit

Comment: @GeorgeMok Great, I've updated my answer to include that patch (thanks for the tip!).

Answer (score 0):

I am referring to the post from "applmath". You can easily run his code from the terminal like this.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Canon iX6800 series" to activate -- Run "Canon iX6800 series"
delay 0.25
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Canon iX6800 series"
    click menu item "Canon iX6800 series" of menu "Window" of menu bar 1
    click menu item "Settings" of menu "Printer" of menu bar 1 -- Select "Settings"
    click radio button "Utility" of tab group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 -- Select "Utility"
    click button "Print Test Page" of tab group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 -- Select "Print Test Page"
    key code 53 -- escape key (selects Cancel)
end tell
tell application "Canon iX6800 series" to quit -- Quit the app'
```

Or you could create a file with AppleScript that would be executed when you enter e.g. "Printer" as a command like this.

Create a file called Printer

```
touch Printer
```

Now make this executable

```
chmod +x Printer
```

Write this in the file Printer.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "Canon iX6800 series" to activate -- Run "Canon iX6800 series"
delay 0.25
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Canon iX6800 series"
    click menu item "Canon iX6800 series" of menu "Window" of menu bar 1
    click menu item "Settings" of menu "Printer" of menu bar 1 -- Select "Settings"
    click radio button "Utility" of tab group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 -- Select "Utility"
    click button "Print Test Page" of tab group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 -- Select "Print Test Page"
    key code 53 -- escape key (selects Cancel)
end tell
tell application "Canon iX6800 series" to quit -- Quit the app
```

Move this file to `/usr/local/bin`

```
sudo mv Printer /usr/local/bin
```

Change the rights of this file to protect it from manipulation

```
sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/bin/Printer && chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/Printer
```

Now, if you just enter "Printer" in the terminal, you can run this AppleScript.