# Where is "Get Info" application information stored?

Tags: applescript, command-line, applications, automator

I am trying to come up with a way to write a script that needs to be able to edit settings within "Get Info" application properties. I can't seem to find the information anywhere; I tried mdls, (running a diff before and after changing a get info setting), checking in Library, etc., but haven't had any luck. I don't care what I need to write it in, Apple Script, Automator, etc., but need to be able to change these settings.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

[image: Screenshot of the Get Info window of the Spotify app]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you post a screen shot of this get info app? Or look in the Apple menu - which Application has the mouse and keyboard focus when this window is active? [I’m guessing you’re using Automator and “watch me do” for this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/255092/5472), but I’d rather be sure before trying to help.

Comment: Here is a screenshot: [Spotify "Get Info"](https://i.postimg.cc/3RwnRV15/Screen-Shot-2022-09-01-at-1-13-41-PM.png)

Thanks!

Comment: I am referring to the built in feature, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Does anyone have any advice? I can't find anything online referencing this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A lot of these are related to the file system or what the file actually is - what particular setting(s) are you talking about?

Comment: @red_menace "scale to fit below built-in camera" is the primary concern.

Comment: Your question is fairly general and doesn't have a simple answer. Should it be rewritten as 'How to script the "scale to fit below built-in camera" setting for apps?'.

Comment: My first guess is that they are stored in Extended Attributes. Bear in mind that not all apps will give you the option to not use the extra screen real estate in the new laptops.

Comment: @benwiggy thanks for your comment. I have wrote the following function:

`func getAttributes(path: String) -> [FileAttributeKey: Any] {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let attributes = try! fileManager.attributesOfItem(atPath: path)
    // print("Attributes:\n \(attributes)")
    for (key, value) in attributes {
        print("\(key) - \(value)")
    }
    // print("Atributes")
    return attributes
}`

Comment: You're scripting in Swift? Why not just use the xattr shell command?

Comment: The extended attributes I can find are these:
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileSize) - 96
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileOwnerAccountName) - root
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileSystemNumber) - 16777233
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileType) - NSFileTypeDirectory
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileExtensionHidden) - 1
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileReferenceCount) - 3
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID) - 0
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileCreationDate) - 2022-05-31 07:09:31 +0000
NSFileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFilePosixPermissions) - 493

Comment: Those aren't extended attributes. Just use xattr on the command line.

Comment: @benwiggy this is the third language I've tried, I don't really care what it's written in. I can't find a single mention of that checkbox anywhere in the docs. Furthermore, I did try xattr but it also didn't output all attributes/the one I'm searching for.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: It could be a data value within com.apple.FinderInfo, for instance.

Comment: TBH, I'd just live with the notch. ;-)

Comment: I mean, yes you're completely right, it's arguably worse with the checkbox enabled on a per app basis, lol. But I am at the point where I used too many hours and need to figure it out for my own good

Comment: and by "good" I mean sanity